# CommerceKickstart; Slideshow content/pages disappear if I add a Product Reference field under Slideshow Content Type

Tags: views

I am trying to add the "Add to Cart" button into a Slideshow. The problem is as soon as i add a Product Reference field under the Slideshow Content Type, if i than go to Content>Manage Content the Slideshow Content Type/pages are no longer visible.
At this point to add a new slideshow image/content i have to go to Products>Add a Product.
Somethings not functioning right.
Im pretty sure theres something that im doing wrong but i cant figure it out....

Answer (score 0):

if you want an slideshow that will display products you may want to create an slideshow that will display "product displays" and add to it an relationship with the products entity, then grab from there stuff like "add to cart" button, images, prices etc.

fields in the view may be in form of :

- [product_display] - title
- [product_ref] - price
- [product_ref] - img
- [product_ref] - commerce line item "add to cart"

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure thats what I've been doing.....
Ok so i started over.

1. I duplicated the Slideshow View (renamed it "Slideshow(Product)"
2. I created a new content type ("Slideshow(Product")
3. In "Slideshow(Product)" View i did the following:

3a. RELATIONSHIPS : Content: Product

3b. FILTER CRITERIA: Content: Type (= Slideshow(product)), Content: Published (Yes)

3c. FIELDS: Field: Title (Title), (Products referenced by field_product) Commerce Product: Images
(Products referenced by field_product) Commerce Product: Add to Cart form (Add to Cart form)

In:  Content types > Slideshow(product) > Manage display
All required fields are Enabled (not Hidden)

Where am i going wrong here?...... :/

I remember reading a thread where a person wanted to do exactly the same thing as i am trying to do and all he did(according to him) was add a Product Reference field in the original Slideshow(at least thats what he said he did, and apparently it worked...